# How effective is rinsing in removing microbes from surfaces

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, virology

Microbes including viruses stay alive on surfaces depending upon the type of the surface like steel, wood, plastic, glass, marble etc. How effective is rinsing these surfaces with tap water in removing the existing microbes. I couldn't find this information on internet. Please provide source for your answer.

Comment: I guess this is too broad: there are many types of surfaces, some with pores (marble, wood), and also a huge variety of microbes. The method by which they attach often has nothing to do with biology (exception: biofilms). If you're curious to do some experimenting yourself, you can apply soot to a sample surface and try removing it by rinsing.,

Comment: I am not asking answer for every microbe and every surface. Whatever research and information is available on the subject is valuable and can be used to theorize.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and then [edit] or delete your question accordingly. In particular, avoid "questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer".  ——— We also expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

Rinsing the surface will make the micro organism growth static on the surface i.e it removes the micro organisms from the surface,but it is only for time being.But it is not effective in killing the micro organism.Mostly in labs,70% Alchohol is used to disinfect the surface.It is more effective in killing the organism.

Comment: As you are a new contributor, can I make the friendly suggestion that you would benefit from reviewing the [Help on Answering questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). One key point is that stating an opinion is not sufficient. Evidence should be cited in support of your answer, generally in the form of references to papers or websites, preferably with links. Otherwise nobody can judge. Otherwise, how can the poster or readers judge whether your answer is correct or not? And it's worthwhile reading the section on only answering well-asked questions.